# PHP DOMDocument move a node to the top of a document

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to reorganize scripts and styles in a piece of HTML that looks like:

```
<script ...></script>
<style ... >
<script ...></script>
<script ...></script>
<style ... >
<script ...></script>
```

So what I want to do is iterate over all style elements and move them to the top of the document. So that the end result looks like:

```
<style ... >
<style ... >
<script ...></script>
<script ...></script>
<script ...></script>
<script ...></script>
```

I managed to iterate over the DOM Document and remove the matched nodes, but I don't know how to add them again to the top of the document.

```
foreach(iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('style')) as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't remove them, simply use `insertBefore` to place them before the first script element.

Comment: @CBroe That looks like a very smart approach. I will research that method and get it done. Thanks for your help!